# Order of a Linear difference equation Vs order of its equivalent matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory

I am learning Linear algebra from MIT ocw, and this is the first time I'm seeing the term 'Linear Difference (recurrence?) equation.'

From browsing the web, this is what I have understood:
A linear difference equation is a series where the $n^{th}$ term is generated from some linear combination of its previous terms: 


ex: $$ F_n = a_1F_{n-1}+a_2F_{n-1}+b$$

This example is *"second order"* because the $n^{th}$ term is generated from the  previous *two* terms. It would be homogeneous if $b=0$.

By this understanding, the Fibonacci series is a "second order homogenus equation".

The Fibonacci series re-written as matricies is in the form: $u_{k+1}=Au_k$
.
This [pdf](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/diagonalization-and-powers-of-a/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.9sum.pdf), calls $u_{k+1}=Au_k$    a  *first order* difference equation (because the $k+1 ^{th}$ vector is depends only on $k^{th}$ vector?).

So I want to know if this is a mistake, or if we associate a seperate order to the same series written in two different forms. (and if my understanding of linear difference equations in this context is correct)

fibonacci series as matrices:$$ \\ \begin{bmatrix} F_n \\ F_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} F_{n-1} \\ F_{n-2} \end{bmatrix} $$

---

Note: I do not want to know about difference equations in its full generality, I just want to know whatever is immediately relevant to my course.